# IdentityServer ErrorContext and getting as much detail as I can

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I have this Error page in my IdentityServer code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Error(string errorId)
{
    var vm = new ErrorViewModel();

    // retrieve error details from identityserver
    var error = await interaction.GetErrorContextAsync(errorId);
    if (error != null)
    {
        vm.Error = error;
    }

    return View("Error", vm);
}
```

In the Error view, I display the `Error` and `ErrorDescription` properties (**only on non-production environments**). However, I'm not getting very useful feedback from IdentityServer. Just an "Invalid client configuration" warning. If I debug IdentityServer locally, I can see more output in a console window, such as "This redirect URL was passed in, but I only accept these redirect URLs", followed by the expected input.

How can I get as much detail on a configuration error as possible from IdentityServer?